# Is it possible to build a flash application with multitouch and tag recognition ability on Microsoft Surface (now PixelSense) table?

Tags: flash, pixelsense

We need to do a presentation on a surface table in a very short time.
We are buying a pixelsense table very soon.

We want to know, is it possible to build a flash application with multitouch and tag recognition ability on Microsoft Surface (now PixelSense) table?

From this article, It appears that we can run a flash application on a table, making use of the microsoft table's multi touch ability?
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html

But what about tag recognition ability?
I need some guide on whether this is possible in flash!

Answer (score 0):

From all I've been reading on MDN, it sounds like PixelSense does not support touch events within the browser.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/22da3ecf-de5e-48f6-adc8-cf3e20af044f

You could use an application embedding a headless browser, loading the SWF into it. But that wouldn't give you the touch API, based on this discussion:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/77201345-2150-4935-953a-3554dabfc05b

And based on this discussion in the Adobe forums Adobe AIR does not seem support touch API integration as well:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/4526917

I haven't tested myself, since I don't have access to a Microsoft Surface/Pixel Sense device.

Answer (score 0):

We just received our PixelSense table and the first thing I tried was to build an AS3 Flash app with multitouch and it works perfectly.

But I'm pretty sure that you can't use the tag recognition directly in Flash, maybe you can build a recognition app that runs in the background and passes its data to the Flash app.